# Removing Widgets From Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've created a Wordpress child theme and now want to remove the widgets from the sidebar. However all the tutorials are not helping.

Each one says to add the following code to my functions.php file in my child theme:

```
<?php
function unregister_old_sidebars() {
    unregister_sidebar('sidebar-1');
   }
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unregister_old_sidebars' );
?>
```

However, do I copy the entire functions file from the parent theme and copy it in a new functions.php in my child theme, or is this the ONLY code that I put into my child theme functions.php file.

Nothing I do seems to be working.

Comment: Are you wanting to remove the option to completely ADD widgets to the sidebar, or are you just wanting the sidebar to not show in the theme?

Comment: Just want the sidebar not to show. trying to make a full page width web page